# Experience Cloud Page Name

Tags: community, community-builder, experience-cloud

I am trying to use `LWC Navigation` to community page. I Understand we have to give Page Name. My question is where can I get Page Name and how can I get the page name if it is under an hierarchy.

```
 this[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                pageName: 'my-page'
            },
            state: {
                labelKey: labelKeyVal,
                language:'en_US'
            }
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. We have to use `name`
instead of `pageName` and we have to use `My_Page__c`

```
[NavigationMixin.Navigate]({
            type: 'comm__namedPage',
            attributes: {
                name: 'My_Page__c'
            },
            state: {
                labelKey: labelKeyVal,
                language:'en_US'
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks; helped me figure out my issue. Realized the __c is required on the page name.